# JQuery event .load() not firing randomly on dynamicaly created image

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image, onload

Ok, I think it's best if I throw the code in there and then explain it so you get what I'm trying to do. I basicaly followed ('kinda) this code sample [here](https://gist.github.com/gustavohenke/9073132) and adapted it to work with my data.

```
getBase64Image: function () {
    var self = this,
        svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(this.svg),
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
        ctx = null,
        img = document.createElement("img");
    $("body").append($(img).attr("id", "tmpImg").css("visibility", "hidden"));
    canvas.setAttribute("width", (self.Width * 5).toString() + "px");
    canvas.setAttribute("height", (self.Height * 5).toString() + "px");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, (self.Width * 5), (self.Height * 5));
    $(img).on("load", function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, (self.Width * 5), (self.Height * 5));
        var event = jQuery.Event("pngexportcomplete");
        event.image64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").split(",")[1];
        event.time = new Date();
        $(self).trigger(event);
        //I added this based on this**
    }).each(function () {
        if (this.complete) $(this).load();
    });
    img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(svgData));
}
```

** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached)

Then I have an event listener attached to this element waiting for the `pngexportcomplete` event, and I basically send that over with a `__doPostBack();` (yes, I'm working with ASP webforms).

### Problem

The main problem I have is that the `load` event does **not** consistently get fired. It sometimes does, but sometimes fails to enter that code portion, and I can't seem to find what are the steps to reproduce it. In other words, it appears to be random.

But, ever since Einstein, we know that coincidences are seldom, if not unexistent. So I'm asking you all if you can think of something that might be wrong with the existing code.

PS: Once it starts failing it keeps on failing. But it doesn't start failing always at the same time, or at least I'm too blind to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nailed it**. I was trying to load an SVG image's URL data into canvas (not any image, svg). The problem was caused by the masks. We used masks on svg paths to create 'holes' in the objects. We recently decided against it (since those holes were still capturing mouse events and couldn't get rid of them) and went for the multiple 'M's on a single path's `d` attribute like this:

```
<path d="M0,0 ... zM90,30 ... zM23,23">
```

And it got rid of the bug! I had already tracked it to being an issue of the canvas not loading/liking one of the svg elements, because anytime I deleted some of the elements it started working again.
But it turns out it was those ugly masks, so **beware** anyone, canvas doesn't like an svg with masks, but the behaviour is inconsistent (sometimes it *did* work). Seems to be the negative values in the masks viewBox attribute, but I haven't got any more time to test it.

But anyway, just keep it in mind. Hopefully one day it will get fixed!